# clarification with a shell script

Tags: shell

Can somebody explain how `echo "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"` would print `~` in case the `PWD` evaluates to `$HOME`. Never read about such replacement using echo. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `echo` it is your shell makes [Parameter Expansion using `${parameter/pattern/string}` syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> The `pattern` is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
>   expansion. Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern
>   against its value is replaced with string. If pattern begins with `‘/’`,
>   all matches of pattern are replaced with string. Normally only the
>   first match is replaced. If pattern begins with `‘#’`, it must match at
>   the beginning of the expanded value of parameter. If pattern begins
>   with `‘%’`, it must match at the end of the expanded value of parameter.
>   If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the / following
>   pattern may be omitted. If parameter is `‘@’` or `‘*’`, the substitution
>   operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the
>   expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable
>   subscripted with `‘@’` or `‘*’`, the substitution operation is applied to
>   each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant
>   list.

It [doesn't look like POSIX supports it](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

In your case, it replaces the value of `$HOME` envvar (not the string `'$HOME'` literally) with `~` in the output if `PWD` envvar starts with it.

Comment: You could use `${PWD#$HOME}` which is supported by POSIX. It won't take you all the way, but something similar could be constructed, perhaps with a temp variable.

Comment: beautifully explained @J.F. Sebastian. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: For those who want to read on parameter expansion by the bash, here is a good link http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-parameter-expansion